# Excel Table Ranking

Tags: excel, sorting, rank

I have a data table with a number of categories on the left and the same along the top. For each row, I would like to create a separate ranked table displaying the categories along the top of the original table in order from largest to smallest. The screenshot below shows the source table and intended result as an example.

Intended source table and resultant tables:

[image: Intended source table and resultant tables]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you want formula or vba?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of the INDEX and RANK formulas. In cell D10, you could put this formula:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$G$2,1,RANK(D3,$D$3:$G$3,1))
```

The issue will be copying and pasting that down will adjust the formula vertically, but your list runs horizontally, but you could correct for that manually if you don't have a lot of data. If you do and want the convenience of copy/paste, there would be options for making that happen. To adjust manually, just change D3 to D4 in the next cell down, D5 in the cell below that, and so on.